# Automate xmodem file upload

Tags: ruby, bash, serial-port, xmodem

I have a device where a software update is done by uploading a file through xmodem.

I was able to do this in two ways using the lrzsz (http://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) package.

1) Using screen

```
screen /dev/tty.myserialdevice 115200
```

and then

```
^A:exec !! sz -X file.bin
```

or

2) Using cu

```
cu -l /dev/tty.myserialdevice -s 115200
```

and then

```
~+lsz -X file.bin
```

Now I would like to write a script (preferably a ruby or a bash script) to automate the file upload.

Is there a way to pipe the file into screen or cu or use standard input?
When I tried to write a script I only got to the point of opening a connection.
But even then I had problems to properly close this connection again.

Comment: +1 only for using xmodem, what i used last time in approx in 1993 in FIDO and BBS sites... ;) ;)

Comment: Well I wouldn't be using it if I didn't had to :( But thanks that eases the pain a little bit ;)

Comment: Try the `expect` command. Google for examples. The `expect` allows you write commands into script as you usually enters them, so with rightly constructed `expect script` you should be able escape the `cu` with `~` and send the right `sz` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you are still having this problem, but I just recently had to piece together something for a similar situation.

I used screen to automate this portion, as it has some command line options to run in the background.  First, I create a detached screen session, like this:

```
    screen -d -m /dev/tty.myserialdevice 115200
```

Then, I can reference my created session with the -p0 option, and give it a command to execute with -X, which in this case is a command to screen itself to start an xmodem file transfer.

```
    screen -p0 -X exec \!\! sz -X filetosend
```

I had noticed in other places on the web that .\!\! was also sometimes used, so keep this in mind to try if you still have problems.